# Symfony 3.1: configuration of ldap component as service

Tags: ldap, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm writing my first Symfony app and and I need authenticate users over LDAP/AD, but I run out of documentation...

I found many solutions for use [LdapClient](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Ldap/LdapClient.html), but it tagged as deprecated. So, i check for use the new one [Ldap](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Ldap/Ldap.html) class as recommended, but I not found documentation for use it. The documentation of Ldap component for the current version (3.1) suggest to use LdapClient yet! It isn't updated yet?

I don't know how to do: must we create an adapter for add a Ldap service? If so, how to proceed?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this cookbook article for configuring LDAP authentication using the builtin Symfony component:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/ldap.html

I also have a bundle I maintain that includes LDAP authentication that works well with AD called [LdapToolsBundle](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle). It has documentation on the main page for the `app/config/config.yml` entries needed to configure your domain for use in the bundle, and also some details on configuring authentication in `app/config/security.yml` [here](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/LDAP-Authentication-Provider.md).

The bundle above provides a LDAP service called `ldap_tools.ldap_manager` that can be used to query/create/modify different types AD objects.

Comment: Nice! Thank you! I was looking for a bundle that fully operates with AD and Symfony 3.1, I found finally! However I can't assign roles according to AD groups in config.yml.
`security:
    guard:
        roles:`
I tested "AdminsGroupName", "OU=AdminsGroupName", OU=GroupsParentsWithoutDomain", "OU=AdminsGroupName, OU=GroupsParentsWithDomain"... The user is still logged in ROLE_USER :( An idea?

Comment: No problem, glad you find it useful! For the roles you want to do `ldap_tools: security: roles: ROLE_NAME: [ 'AdminsGroupName' ]` (in the `app/config/config.yml` file). There's some more information on that [here](https://github.com/ldaptools/ldaptools-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/LDAP-Authentication-Provider.md#mapping-ldap-groups-to-roles). I plan on adding support for mapping groups by DN, GUID, or SID (in addition to name) in the near future. Right now you can only map groups by their common name.

Comment: Great :) So the mapping groups works only by usernames (**sAMAccountName?**) right now. `roles: ROLE_ADMIN: '_sAMAccountName_'` (tested w or w/o hooks and quotes) doesn't work for me (logged as ROLE_USER), but I can define `default_role: ROLE_ADMIN`. It's curious...

Comment: It maps the groups by `cn`. However, I just made a few changes to the master branch this weekend, and I'll tag a new version eventually. You can now map by CN (name), GUID, SID, or DN. You can also change the name attribute if you want to map based off the `sAMAccountName` as well in the newer version: `ldap_tools: security: role_attributes: name: sAMAccountName`.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my Blog:

https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/

This requires [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and [FR3DLdapBundle](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle), but I think if you go through all that documentation you should be able to get LDAP/AD integration with Symfony3 working.

---

EDIT #2

Below is a second easier solution:

https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/09/07/symfony-ldap-component-ad-authentication/

Comment: I tested this way, but it's not suitable for my project and too heavy to setup. Thanks anyway!